# Deleting the selected option from a select box

Tags: javascript

How do I go about deleting the selected option (highlighted option) from a select box (drop-down list)?

Expected result: Once a selection has been made from the select box, at the click of the button "Delete" the selected option.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
<select id="drop1" id="choices">
  <option value="Red">Red</option>
  <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
  <option value="Green">Green</option>
    <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
    <option value="Black">Black</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Delete" name="delete">

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a javascript function:

```
<input type="button" onclick="removeOptionSelected();" value="Delete" name="delete">


  function removeOptionSelected()
{
  var elSel = document.getElementById('drop1');
  var i;
  for (i = elSel.length - 1; i>=0; i--) {
    if (elSel.options[i].selected) {
      elSel.remove(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very easy with jQuery.  I recommend you use that library. Giving your delete button an ID:

```
$('#deletebtn').on('click', function(){
    $('#drop1').find(':selected').remove();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rWcne/

Answer (score 0):

A jquery-less way -> Use the select box object's remove method and selectedIndex.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_select_remove.asp